# Extract categorical coeffients and all p-values from a mixed model into a data table

Tags: r, for-loop, mixed-models

Here is a reproduceable code and sample data
I want to achieve a final data table with 3 columns: 1. exposure quantile 2. OR/RR 3. PV

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 100
dat = data.frame(ID = rep(c(1:25),times=4 ) ,
                 Score = rnorm(n, mean=0.3, sd=0.8))
                 
dat = dat %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(exposure1 = rep(c(rnorm(1, mean=6, sd=1.8))),
                exposure2 = rep(c(rnorm(1, mean=3, sd=0.6))),
                age = rep(c(rnorm(1, mean=40, sd=15))))%>%
  ungroup()%>%
  dplyr::mutate(exposure1_quantile = cut(exposure1, breaks = 4, labels = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")),
                exposure2_quantile = cut(exposure2, breaks = 4, labels = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")))

exposures_var = c("exposure1_quantile","exposure2_quantile")
exposure_var_labels("exposure1 Q1","exposure1 Q2 ", "exposure 1 Q3", 
                    "exposure2 Q1","exposure2 Q2 ", "exposure2 Q3")
age="age"
outcome = "Score"
exposure_data_table = c()

for(i in 1:length(exposures_var)){
  exp = exposures_var[i]
  fixed_effects_formula = paste0(outcome, "~",exp,"+",age)
  fixed_effects_formula = as.formula(fixed_effects_formula)
  mixedmodel = lme(fixed =fixed_effects_formula, random = ~1|ID, data=dat, method = "ML")
  for(m in 2:4){
    v = mixedmodel$coefficients$fixed[m]
    
    vector = c(exp , v)
    #P=p value for every quantile (HOW TO ADD?)
    #exposure_name = exposure_var_labels[?] (HOW TO ADD LABEL)
    exposure_data_table = rbind(exposure_data_table, vector)
    
   
  }
  
}

exposure_data_table = as.data.table(exposure_data_table)
colnames(exposure_data_table)=c("Exposure","RR")#,"pv")
view(exposure_data_table)
```

I first used anova to try and get the pvalue but it didnt work.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but you might look at `lmerTest` package, which uses an ANCOVA to estimate p-values for multi-level models.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with lme function not lmer?

Answer (score 0):

I think a `tidymodels` approach using `lme` would work well here:

```r
library(nlme)
library(tidymodels)
library(multilevelmod)
library(data.table)

lme_spec <- 
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lme", random = ~ 1 | ID)

Map(function(exp) {

  fixed_effects_formula <- as.formula(paste0("Score~",exp,"+ age +", 0))
 
  lme_spec %>% 
    fit(fixed_effects_formula, data = dat) %>%
    broom.mixed::tidy() %>%
    filter(effect == "fixed", grepl("exposure", term)) %>%
    select(term, estimate, std.error, p.value)
  }, exposures_var) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  as.data.table()
#>                    term    estimate std.error   p.value
#> 1: exposure1_quantileQ1 -0.16147364 0.3532834 0.6525497
#> 2: exposure1_quantileQ2  0.22318505 0.2719366 0.4214784
#> 3: exposure1_quantileQ3  0.24976757 0.3484126 0.4817411
#> 4: exposure1_quantileQ4  0.14177064 0.4020702 0.7280757
#> 5: exposure2_quantileQ1  0.28976458 0.4191198 0.4972840
#> 6: exposure2_quantileQ2  0.19907863 0.2699164 0.4693496
#> 7: exposure2_quantileQ3  0.35040767 0.2827229 0.2295436
#> 8: exposure2_quantileQ4 -0.09587234 0.3533819 0.7889412
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Not working properly
Categorical variables has 3 levels not four (we compare it to the baseline level which is categorical 1. 
Can do this via another method? like a loop

Comment: @SariKatish I thought that's what you wanted. I added a zero intercept to the formula on purpose to achieve this. Just change `as.formula(paste0("Score~",exp,"+ age +", 0))` to `as.formula(paste0("Score~",exp,"+ age"))`